# Select Multiple items in listbox in wpf using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, select, listbox

I want to set multiple selection in a `ListBox` using c#.

For example, I have a list of values I want to set these values as selected in the `ListBox`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MyListBox.SelectedItems.Add(item1);
MyListBox.SelectedItems.Add(item2);
.....
```

Comment: What if SelectedItems is null? Is it possible that SelectedItems is null?

Answer (score 7):

You did not explain much, hopefully your are doing this the WPF way...

Create an `IsSelected` property on your data items then give the style to your `ListBoxItem`s that selects them whenever the `IsSelected` is enabled:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then change the property on your data items, and raise the `OnPropertyChanged` event.